# Matrix multiplication throwing an error when second matrix has only one column

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

First off, it's kind of exciting to be asking a question on Stack Overflow as I've long-time wanted to get into coding but haven't really been able to start.

I'm trying to make a matrix multiplication function in Python **without** using NumPy. I've almost finished my code, but I'm getting an error whenever I try to multiply matrix  "A" by a matrix "B" with only one column.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_multiply(A,B):
row_A = len(A)
col_A = len(A[0])
row_B = len(B)
col_B = len(B[0])
if col_A != row_B:
    return("Invalid matrices")
else:
    result = np.zeros((col_B,row_A))
    for i in range(row_A): # iterate through columns of Y
        for j in range(col_B): # iterate through rows of Y
            for k in range(col_A):
                result[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]
    return result
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 13, in matrix_multiply
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I assume this is a problem with the "result[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]" part.

My code works perfectly for any other-sized matrix, but when there's one column I get this index error. What's going on?

Here's an example:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
B = np.array([[2,3],[4,5],[5,6]])

matrix_multiply(A,B)

array([[25., 31.],
   [36., 45.]])
```

But when I do...

```
v = np.array([[4,3,1],[6,7,2]])
g = np.array([[3],[1],[4]])

matrix_multiply(v,g)
```

I get the error.

Comment: Try `result[j][i] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]`. I have swapped `i` and `j` in the `result`. You will realize it if you look at `result = np.zeros((col_B,row_A))`

Comment: I did this but the axes were swapped for the dot product when comparing to      np.matmul(A,B). Should I just use np.swapaxes(), or is there a more "elegant" solution?

Comment: You can transpose your final result as `result = result.T`. You didn't provide any data to try out your code so we can just provide suggestions and not a working answer

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm still learning how to give information and ask for the right questions. I'll edit my original post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments, you need to swap the order of indices while filling up your `result` matrix and then take the transpose of the final array

Problem: Your index `i`  runs on the length of `row_A` as `for i in range(row_A)` and index `j` runs on the length of `col_B` as `for j in range(col_B):` **BUT** while defining empty `result` array you swap the dimensions because you use `result = np.zeros((col_B,row_A))`, i.e., you first define column dimension and then row dimension. Hence either you swap `i` and `j` inside your for loop as I did below OR you swap the variables while initializing the `result` and then use `[i][j]` as you were doing. Then you won't need a transpose.

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_multiply(A,B):
    row_A = len(A)
    col_A = len(A[0])
    row_B = len(B)
    col_B = len(B[0])
    print (row_B, col_B)
    if col_A != row_B:
        return("Invalid matrices")
    else:
        result = np.zeros((col_B,row_A))
        for i in range(row_A): # iterate through columns of Y
            for j in range(col_B): # iterate through rows of Y
                for k in range(col_A):
                    result[j][i] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]
        return result
```

---

**Example 1**

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
B = np.array([[2,3],[4,5],[5,6]])

result = matrix_multiply(A,B).T
print (result)

# array([[25., 31.],
#    [36., 45.]])
```

**Example 2**

```
v = np.array([[4,3,1],[6,7,2]])
g = np.array([[3],[1],[4]])

result = matrix_multiply(v,g)
print (result)
# [[19. 33.]]
```

Comment: So interesting. Do you know why the transpose is necessary, or why this quirk is occurring? I'm still getting used to how Python operates so I'm wondering why the transpose is necessary instead of just "result[j][i]". Thank you, this does work!

Comment: @an_altar_of_plagues: Check the explanation in my edited answer.